# How to use Capybara without type: :feature?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

All of my specs look like:

```
describe 'Do Something', type: :feature do
```

Is there a way to use Capybara for all specs, or specs within a file or folder?

Yes, they are all in the features folder.

I know rspec-rails supports this with `infer_spec_type_from_file_location!`, but I am not using rspec-rails and it is not a Rails app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement it by yourself. Looking at the [relevant code](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/configuration.rb) from rspec-rails, this seem pretty straight forward.

The most relevant bit is the [`define_derived_metadata`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/950da552/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb#L1296-L1314) method:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  escaped_path = %r{spec/features/}

  config.define_derived_metadata(file_path: escaped_path) do |metadata|
    metadata[:type] ||= :feature
  end
end
```

(I currently have no project to test this on, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.)